How to Add a "Today" Button to Angular Material Datepicker and Handle Date Changes?
I'm using Angular Material 14 and the datepicker component, and I need to add a "Today" button in the footer of the datepicker popup. The button should reset the current date selection to today, close the datepicker, and update the input field. Additionally, I want the datepicker to close by default when any other date is selected.
Here’s the HTML structure I started with, where the "Today" button is displayed, but it overrides the default datepicker events:
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="value" (dateChange)="closeDatepicker()">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker (closed)="closeDatepicker()">
        <mat-calendar (selectedChange)="dateSelected($event)"></mat-calendar>
        <mat-datepicker-actions>
            <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="onToday()">Today</button>
        </mat-datepicker-actions>
   </mat-datepicker>

The Problem
While the "Today" button is displayed using the above HTML, it overrides the default datepicker's dateChange events. I need a solution where clicking the "Today" button selects today’s date and closes the picker, while selecting any other date also closes the datepicker as expected.
